# JQuery each count result error

Tags: jquery, each

I have a button of which voids the last `tr` in a table. Each time it does this the total is worked out again using function `mainTotalCalc()`.

The total is worked out through using `.each` and classes.

The issue arises when i get to one last row remaining. The total will remain as the last total. It never reaches 0.00

Now i think i can see why, as the JQ each considers the last total in the variable.

I am stuck on how to make the last remaining row be voided whilst the total calculates correctly.

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/MKSL3/3/) (But parseFloat does not seem to work here)

**The JS/JQ**

```
function mainTotalCalc() {
    var activetableID = $("li.till_table_button.active").attr('id');
     // alert(activetableID);
    var tablenumber = $("#"+activetableID).data("tableref");
     // alert(tablenumber); //testing

     var newtotal=0,total=0;

     $('.till__tablepanel_table_'+tablenumber+'_row__totalprice').each( function(i) {
      var number = $(this).text();
       //alert(content);
       //num = parseInt(number);
      num = parseFloat(number);
      newtotal += num;
       // alert(number); //testing

      totalpriceDecimal = newtotal.toFixed(2);
      $('#till__totalpanel_table_'+tablenumber+'_price').html(newtotal.toFixed(2));
       // alert(totalpriceDecimal); 
      i++;

     });

}
```

**Before Last Void**
[image: before void]

**After Last Void (Total remains as 1.00 and shouldn't be)**
[image: after void]

Comment: What triggers `mainTotalCalc()` to be fired?

Comment: its the last thing called in a function which initiates the `tr:last` removal. The removal works perfectly, and adding rows calculates perfectly. Its just when voiding them, the last one has an issue. I think its something to do with the +=, but i am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a guard condition if there are no more rows:

```
if ($('.till__tablepanel_table_0_row__totalprice').length == 0)
  $('#till__totalpanel_table_0_price').html('0.00');
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/JNPC5/)

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for, thankyou so much. I tried so many ways, but not this. Awesome!

Comment: I see the issue now as there were not any rows for the calculation to take place. This solves the issue perfectly. I just did not realise that no rows meant no calculation previously.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that the total is being updated **inside** the `.each` loop.

If there are now rows to total, this will not run.

Modify your function as follows:

```
function mainTotalCalc() {
    $('.till__tablepanel_table_'+tablenumber+'_row__totalprice').each( function(i) {
      var number = $(this).text();
       //alert(content);
       //num = parseInt(number);
      num = parseFloat(number);
      newtotal += num;
       // alert(number); //testing

      totalpriceDecimal = newtotal.toFixed(2);
       // alert(totalpriceDecimal); 
      i++;

     });
     // Move this line outside of the .each loop
     $('#till__totalpanel_table_'+tablenumber+'_price').html(newtotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: i had tried this, and understand now the error. The actual rows do not exist to calculate a total. Thats why this approach did not work. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You have missed **newtotal** variable declaration, simply do this:

```
function mainTotalCalc() {
    var newtotal = 0.0; // MISSED VARIABLE DECLARATION
    $('.till__tablepanel_table_0_row__totalprice').each( function() {         
      var number = $(this).text();
      console.log('number: ' + number);

      newtotal += parseFloat(number);          
      console.log('newtotal= ' + newtotal);

      totalpriceDecimal = newtotal.toFixed(2);
      $('#till__totalpanel_table_0_price').html(totalpriceDecimal);
      // alert(totalpriceDecimal);

     });   
}
```